# If either party would "pack the Supreme Court", what would be stopping the next administration from just doubling (+1) the number of judges again?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

If either party (i.e. Democrats or Republicans) in the US would proceed to "pack the Supreme Court", what would be stopping the next administration (i.e. after power has switched once again to the other party in an election) from just doubling (plus one) the number of judges again, in order to re-gain a majority of judges that are to their own liking? Nothing?

Comment: In principle, the party packing the Court could pack it with justices who will overturn any new law extending the size of the Court again, no matter how clearly it is phrased. The law ultimately means what the Supreme Court says it means, not what Congress says it means. Then you would have to wait for enough of them to die, or perhaps impeach them if you can get a sufficient majority.

Comment: It's not directly an answer, but there _are_ court reform options other than simply adding more judges, and some of them can't really be "topped" (although they can always be reversed).  For example, changing the qualifications for judges, or the number who have to agree to overturn precedent, or invalidate something on Constitutional grounds (to name some proposals I've seen).

Comment: At a certain point, the eligible population would be a limiting factor.  Not including population growth, this could only be done about 24 times before every adult in the US (~200Mn) becomes a justice.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Functionally, nothing except the regular requirements of passing legislation and nominating justices.

Altering the number of judges on the Supreme Court is as simple as passing legislation through the normal channels, as the Constitution is silent on the *number* of judges on the Court. This was last altered in 1869, when the Judiciary Act of that year set the number at nine; the Chief Justice, and eight associate Justices.

Assuming a presidential administration has the numbers in the House and the Senate to pass such legislation it follows that they also have the required numbers to confirm a nominee, as the elimination of the filibuster for Supreme Court nominations in 2017 ensures that a party in control of the Senate may pass a cloture vote by simple majority in order to end attempts to delay a confirmation vote.

Attempts to filibuster the legislation to expand the Court *could* be successful, depending on the partisan composition of Congress, however given the precedent set in 2017, it is perfectly possible that a filibuster could be overridden by another use of the 'nuclear option'.

Politically, however, the consequences for the credibility of the Court and the Judiciary as a whole would of course be significant, which could make an administration pause before retaliating. The danger of inviting a tit-for-tat response was, in fact, acknowledged by Joe Biden during the [fourth Democratic debate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/10/15/october-democratic-debate-transcript/) in October 2019:

> **Erin Burnett:** Vice President Biden, the Constitution does not specify the number of justices that serve on the Supreme Court. If Roe
> v. Wade is overturned on your watch and you can't pass legislation in
> Congress, would you seek to add justices to the Supreme Court to
> protect women's reproductive rights?
>
> **Joe Biden:** I would not get into court packing. We [add] three justices. Next time around, we lose control, they add three justices.
> We begin to lose any credibility the court has at all.

Comment: Well, it specifies that there is at least one justice by mentioning the position of "Chief Justice" (oddly not in the clause establishing the court, but rather in the impeachment trying clause).  But that's a technicality.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy the implication that there's at least one justice sitting on the court is perfectly clear in the first sentence of article three.  How could "the judicial Power of the United States, ... be vested in one supreme Court" otherwise?  If anything, mention of a "chief" justice implies that there are at least _two_ justices.  But neither of these provisions really _specifies_ any number of justices.  They only imply it.

Comment: "Politically, however, the consequences for the credibility of the Court and the Judiciary as a whole would of course be significant" that ship may have sailed

Comment: @CGCampbell one is the natural extension of the other. If the people appointing judges are shamelessly partisan in their actions, my faith that their appointees are going to be impartial and non-partisan in their decisions is shaken right out of the gate.

Comment: I think there is an element of control wanted.   The more justices the less likely they can be controlled.   That is what politics is about.

Comment: "Politically, however, the consequences for the credibility of the Court and the Judiciary as a whole would of course be significant" - Seems an odd sentiment.  A Court packed with three Trump appointees (one of whom hasn't even been nominated, yet looks set for confirmation in 6 weeks or less) has how much credibility, exactly?

Comment: Biden's answer reminds me of the line from "The Untouchables": **He pulls a knife, you pull a gun. He sends one of yours to the hospital, you send one of his to the morgue!**

Answer (score 10):

In theory, nothing prevents this.  In practice, though, it's not a decision that lies with the president, so it requires a majority vote of both houses of congress in addition to the president's signature.  It's therefore unlikely to occur every four years or eight years even if the present reluctance to increasing the size of the court might abate.  Furthermore, at some point the justices themselves will probably start objecting if the court's size becomes unwieldy, thereby making it difficult to conduct the court's business.

Comment: On the other hand, some countries have big supreme courts where only a set of justices take on each case. So there would be ways to change how SCOTUS works if it were packed to 18 members, although I know change is scary for justices.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim yes, it's certainly possible for the court to be organized such that each case was heard by a subset of justices.  This would probably require additional changes to the legislation, however, since the court's quorum is set by statute.

Comment: While the justices might have an _opinion_ on how many justices there are, it's probably completely irrelevant.  Presumably the reason you want to change the number of justices is because you don't like the current population, so their opinion and the opinion of my cat have equal influence on the outcome.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim In fact there are lower courts in the US that operate that way today, so the model already exists.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That's presumably done to handle the case load of the lower courts are required to handle. SCOTUS gets to decide which cases have sufficient merit for the entire court to deliberate on them. Although I suppose if they operated as subsets they could accept more cases.

Comment: But if you're trying to "pack the court", adding a subsetting provision would counter it, so there's no reason why they would do it.

Comment: @Barmar The idea of subsetting would be that the justices for any given case would be chosen at random (and not known to anyone in advance of the selection), which would limit the potential effect of trying to push a case to the court that appeals specifically to one side or the other since you don't know ahead of time what kind of mix you're going to get.  This could have a potential balancing effect on the SCOTUS in general.  And yes, this would also allow them to look at more cases.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman And why would POTUS or Congress be in favor of that? They all want SCOTUS to be biased in their favor, not unpredictable or balanced.

Comment: @Barmar Certainly - from purely cynical political terms, you are correct that neither side would want that.  However, it might be better from the perspective of the people or for justice as a whole.  As divided as the government is right now it's unlikely they'd be up for this sort of a compromise, though it would definitely reduce the amount of hostility we're seeing from both sides right now.  With such a system in place, the replacement of 1 Justice wouldn't be seen as quite such a big deal.

Comment: @JamesMoore as the president of the Judicial Conference of the United States, the chief justice is required by [statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/331) to report the conference's "recommendations for legislation" annually.  Congress may choose to ignore the opinion of the judicial branch when it specifies the conditions under which the judicial branch will operate, but the opinion is by no means irrelevant.  For example, congress split the eleventh circuit from the fifth circuit in response to a petition from the judges of the fifth circuit.